# How many Ender Crystals are in the End?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Without any Ender Crystals around, killing the Enderdragon is getting easier because they heal him.

But how many Ender Crystals are there in the PC Edition?

Comment: It's variable as far as I know. I assume they are part of the terrain generation.

Comment: @Arperum ok. but do you have any numbers? is there a minimum and a maximum? 8-12 ... 0-Infinity ...

Comment: They are on the main island, the island generally isn't that large, so if you get 20, I'd assume you got unlucky. You'd have to look at the code to get the correct possible range. I think I've had a situation where there where about six, and other situations with 12 or something. It's been quite some time since I went to the end.

Comment: I've just spawned about 5 worlds, I'm poking a wild guess at 12-18 Crystals... (Results were: 12, 16, 17, 14, 13)

Comment: Woah.. This is bizarre. Spawned more worlds and numbers jumped to 22 and 8 ender crystals respectively.

Comment: wow. thats a large range! and thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I did some rigorous testing (as otherwise known as spawning 20 worlds and then count the number of Ender Crystals in each).
*Just make new worlds and use "/say @e[type=EnderCrystal]" in the end. Then, count the number of "entity.EnderCrystal.name" it produces.*

My results were (in chronological order):
12, 16, 17, 14, 13, 15, 22, 8, 14, 8,
16, 5, 12, 9, 19, 16, 13, 24, 22 and 12.

## So, my wild guess is around 4-24 Ender Crystals, based on how big the island is.

Basically, it's pure luck (or the seed you've used). The number of crystals you encounter in each world depends on the size of the End Island. I've noticed that the islands usually center around 12-20 crystals.

Because Ender Crystals (and their obsidian pillars) are generated randomly based on the island size (as @[Shunwoo](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/84398/shunwoo) quoted from the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Obsidian_pillar)), there is NO definite number of Ender Crystals in any world. It will never have the same number of pillars (unless you use the same seed over and over*).

NB: *I do not know if seed affects the generation of obsidian pillars (apart from the number of chunks that the island consists of; the number of rerolls to hit the 20% chance that a pillar will generate), but I know it definately does affect island size.
*So, for all we know, using the same seed over could result in worlds containing 18, 17, 18, 16, 19, 18 pillars respectively)*

Comment: +1 but i won't accept it, because it's a "wild guess"

Comment: @PhilippSander Im not sure that a specific answer can be generated in this case. Minecraft generates each world individually so there is no telling whether a specific amount of crystals spawn/generate. This testing resulted between 4-24 Crystals is a result of that random generating.

Comment: The only thing that could be done is more worlds being generated, to get a larger sample pool. But I doubt anyone would be willing to make more than these 20 world to do this test for some statistics. I'm impressed someone took the time to make 20 new worlds already.

Comment: @Arperum i don't think the ONLY thing that could be done is providing more samples.

Comment: I observe that 12-17 is slightly denser than the rest, so there may be a normal-ish distribution at work here.  Mean is ~14.35, stddev is ~4.945.  I don't know what to make of the fact that like 90% of those are even though.

Comment: @PhilippSander a "wild guess" is pretty good when you're talking about procedurally generated content (given the specific ranges). He did some research, gave you some commands to go further, and gave an answer based on his observations. I'm not even sure you could logically deduce it with the source code if it's part of terrain generation (unless there's a hard min / max, of course).

Comment: It's fair enough to wait a while to see if a better answer arrives, but I think you'll be waiting a while! But who knows, perhaps you'll get a signed note from Jeb. :)

Answer (score 10):

According to the [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Obsidian_pillar):

> Each chunk has a 20% chance of generating an obsidian pillar.

The number isn't fixed, it depends entirely on the size of the End, as it is based on the numbers of chunks your map of the End has. The bigger the island, the more pillars you'll have.

Edit : If you want a range of numbers of pillars, it's : [ 0; +∞ ]
0 when there is no island, and +∞ when you create an endless End map.

Comment: This is true. It's possible to make a superflat End biome, in which case the ender crystals/pillars extend to infinity in every direction. Therefore, as most other people here have said, it depends entirely on the side of your end island, and there are no specific numbers that can be given, aside from wide ranges.

Comment: +1. But note that even a three-chunk island has a >50% chance of spawning no single pillar

Comment: +1 But remember that the End island never exceeds around 50x50 chunks, based on observations.. Like I've had large islands that had only 14 pillars, when another island of the same size had 22.

Comment: @Bergi source ?

Comment: @aytimothy How can you make statements finishing by "based on observations" when you can rely on code ? And yes you can have different results on same size islands as it is a 20% CHANCE

Comment: It's an estimate, and yes - I have no source. But remember one thing: Islands are never infinite in size. They can be huge, but never infinite.

Comment: That's why I added precision in my answer

Comment: @Shunwoo: The source is [Maths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Comment: @Bergi I still don't understand what your "note" is adding to the answer but ok.

Comment: @Shunwoo: You said "*0 when there is no island*", I wanted to add that it still is likely for small islands.

Comment: @Bergi ok ! Now i see your point, and yes of course !